# How can I count unique characteristic strings in one cell?

Tags: string, count, character

I have 3 columns of stacked data. I have a spreadsheet with each row representing a report. In one column, the S/N's are listed for that report and they're all in one cell separated by deliminators. Most everything I've found to try are formulas for a range of cells and not for a single cell. Does anyone have any ideas for me to get a count of the unique serial numbers in the one cell? The serial numbers are a strings of both alpha and numeric characters varying anywhere from 3 to 16 characters. I have over 4000 rows, each row representing a report. That is a lot of manual steps if I have to do each individual report one at a time.

Comment: Welcome, can you please add some more information in regards to a sample of what you have in your dataset, and also what your expected outcome is along with what you have tried and how that outcome is different than you expected.

Comment: I have to run several reports to do an alaysis becuse not one report has all the information I need. As a result, I have to become quite create at times. In this case, I need to know to get veraious quantities of itmes based on the given data. I was able to figure out how to count the number of times Accept, Rework, Scrap and Rework appeared in the column of stacked data(separated by a deliminator). Now I need to know how many s/n's. all the rejected parts and their s/n's are in one column as stacked data. example: STA128L8|STA130L9|STA131L0|STA133L6|STA127L5|
another example; 001|002|003|